# How can I initialize a dense matrix with prepared matrix-like data

Tags: scala, matrix

We can always initialize a dense matrix in breeze like this :

```
import breeze.linalg.{DenseMatrix => BDM}

val mt: BDM[Double] = BDM((1.0,2.0,3.0),(10.0,20.0,30.0))
```

Unfortunately, we cannot initialize it as follows:

```
import breeze.linalg.{DenseMatrix => BDM}

val data: Array[Array[Double]] = Array(Array(1.0,2.0,3.0),Array(10.0,20.0,30.0))

val mt: BDM[Double] = BDM(data)
```

**How can I initialize a dense matrix with prepared matrix-like data like that?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pass a collection into a function expecting a repeating parameter (aka "varargs" in Java) like `DenseMatrix`'s constructor, use `: _*`:

```
val mt: BDM[Double] = BDM(data: _*)
```

Comment: thanks , this option really works in newer version of breeze